# What are all the different effects of the special Pokeballs?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

As I understand it, catching certain pokemon with certain pokeballs provides additional effects other than an easier catch. It even shows what ball you caught a pokemon with when checking its status in your inventory or PC box, implying that it matters. (Or else why keep note of such a thing?) Which pokeballs give additional effects *beyond just increasing the chances of catch* and what are they?

Comment: Gotta love the ninja downvotes. -.-

Comment: What kind of additional effects? AFAIK aside from the catch rate, when a pokemon goes into battle, you see a different animation depending on the ball it was caught with. I.E. your dusk ball example, when a pokemon caught with a dusk ball is brought into battle it comes out of the dusk ball (obviously) and there will be a dark flash when it opens.

Comment: @Domenik if I knew I wouldn't have a question to ask, the game hinted at something but I honestly dont remember what it said.

Comment: [there are 26 varieties of pokeballs so far](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball), IMO this could be a lot more specific

Comment: @ben i had no idea there were so many, i play pokemon extremely casually

Comment: Which generation?  I'm pretty sure the effects vary between generations, as well...

Comment: @ben of those 26 varieties, I'm sure many dont have effects that I'm looking for, so asking about a dozen or so items doesn't seem too broad to me at all

Comment: @margaret clarified the Gen I was asking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few Poké Balls have effects on the Pokémon in them after you catch them. These are the effects:

- **Friend Ball:** Increases the Pokémon's friendship to 200 when you catch it.
- **Luxury Ball:** Increases the rate at which the Pokémon's friendship value grows.
- **Heal Ball:** Fully restores the Pokémon's HP, PP, and status when you catch it.

This information comes from [the bulbapedia Poké Ball page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball) Ben Brocka linked to.